# Query all Children for Parent using Appengine Admin Console Datastore Viewer

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

I have an Entity named RouteCompletion that identifies Route as it's Parent (using Objectify @Parent annotation).

In the AppEngine Admin Console I am able to query for the specific child by writing a standard **key** query.

```
SELECT * FROM RouteCompletion where __key__ = Key('Route',5704906207920128,'RouteCompletion','gc-136985405')
```

returns the expected result:

- name=gc-136985405
- agxzfnRuLWFwaS1kZXZyGgsSCEFjdGl2aXR5IgxnYy0xMzY5ODU0MDUM
- Activity: name=gc-136985405

---

I would like to find all children for that same Parent. I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM RouteCompletion where __key__ = Key('Route',5704906207920128)
```

The query is valid GQL, but returns no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM RouteCompletion where ANCESTOR is Key('Route',5704906207920128)
```

Comment: doesn't work. I get: GQL query error: Encountered "ancestor" at line 1, column 34. Was expecting one of: "false", "null", "true", <INTEGER>, <DOUBLE>, <SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING>, <DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING>, <UNQUOTED_NAME>, <QUOTED_NAME>, <NAME_BINDING_SITE>, <POSITION_BINDING_SITE>

Answer (score 4):

Use `has ancestor` instead of `=`.

```
SELECT * FROM RouteCompletion where __key__ has ancestor Key(Route,5704906207920128)
```